# Buying something online in canadian dollars with us dollars

Tags: credit-card, cad-canadian-dollar

I want to buy something online that only accepts canadian dollars and also paypal(but I want to try not to have to use that). It shows the credit card that I have but the price is listed in canadian dollars. How do I buy the item?

Edit: I forgot to say I live in the US using US dollars

Answer (score 8):

Nothing is stopping you.

I've regularly bought things in U.S. dollars using paypal or my credit card, even though I'm in Canada. Just make sure they ship internationally and that you understand any taxes that may (but shouldn't) occur at the border.

As @blm points out, the credit card company will exchange the currencies themselves at the prevailing exchange rate, but will likely charge you a fee (perhaps 3%, which roughly matches my experience) for the service.

Comment: I think they are looking for info on exchange rate and fees.

Comment: I disagree. The question appears to be how to buy the item ("How do I buy the item?"), not how much the exchange rate and fees will be.

Comment: I agree this answers the question, but I think it could be a better answer by mentioning that the credit card company will convert Canadian to US dollars at the prevailing exchange rate, and that most if not all credit card companies will charge some percentage of the transaction (3% seems to be the usual) as a foreign exchange fee.

Comment: @blm alternately, you could post that comment as an answer.

Comment: @blm, thanks for the comment. I have added your note to my answer.

Comment: It has been my experience that, as well as fees, the spread on the exchange rate that you will get will be high and so there will be an extra cost there.

Comment: To add to @MD-Tech's comment, the credit-card company is "buying" CAN$ in bulk (to send to individual Canadian merchants as payment) at the prevailing inter-bank exchange rate applicable to amounts of multiple thousands (or hundreds of thousands) of dollars, but billing the individual card holders at the (worse) exchange rate applicable to their individual small transactions.

Comment: Thanks @DilipSarwate, I know when I've done this the exchange rate has been ok, but not great, and your explanation makes sense.